# Reading a JSON object in php sent from Nodejs with Fetch module

Tags: php, node.js, fetch

I'm trying to Post a JSON object from Nodejs to a LAMP server. 
I can send the object, but I can't get it from my php script.
I need help about getting the object in the php script.

Always return -- NOT SET -- 
WHY ?
How can I do it ?
Thank You

**My code is:**

```
**In express**

module.exports = function(app){
var fetch = require('node-fetch');  
var request = require('request-promise');

//Save
app.post('/cajaSave', function(req, res) 
{   
    var pago = req.body;  //object to send

    fetch('http://www.myurl/myscript.php',{
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(pago)  
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();          
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);                      
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}); 

My php code is:

<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    $json = $_POST['body'];
    if(isset($_POST['body']))
    {
        $msg = "set";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "not set";
    }
    echo json_encode($msg); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt Altepeter, it worked fine !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON gets dumped into `php://input`

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```